# How to get hash values of youtube video?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am studying about youtube-api, got that I could read lots of contents of the youtube video both public and private. I want to know if I can read the hash values of youtube videos from youtube-api or not. If so, which api and command should I use?

Comment: Why would you need to read the hash value of a video though?

Comment: @ZackVT I am learning the video processing, and read that the local downloaded videos can get the hash value from hashlib, so I want to know if I can read the hash value from online videos directly, and see if there is any difference or not. Is it allowed? and how?